# Frechet/Gateaux differentiability of an integral operator $L^2 \rightarrow R$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, gateaux-derivative

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ be a continuously differentiable function on the real numbers (if needed also infinitely many often differentiable).

Define the Operator $F : L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow R$ for $x \in L^2([0,1])$ by

$F(x)=\int_0^1 f(x(s)) ds $

We assume that $F(x)<A−B∫x(s)^2 ds\leq A$ with constants $A,B>0$.
Hence it is bounded from above but not from below

**Question:**

Is $F$ now Frechet differentiable?

Is $F$ Gateaux differentiable?

**Known:**

If we were looking at $F$ as an operator on $C([0,1])$, then it is Frechet differentiable (as shown for example at wikipedia: [http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet-Ableitung#Integraloperator](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet-Ableitung#Integraloperator) )
But they use that on this space they know that each function is bounded.

Comment: I don't think that this operator is well defined in general.  Take a function which is just barely in $L^2$ and make it so that in any neighborhood of zero it is singular like $x^{-\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon}$ with terms that are both positive and negative.  When you cube this function ($f(x) = x^3$), the positive part and the negative part will both be infinite, so the functional isn't well defined.

Comment: If I assume that F is bounded from above e.g. by $F(x)<A−B∫x(s)^2 ds$ with constants $A,B>0$. Would that be enough to make it well defined? (I added this assumption to the question)

Comment: Let's consider $f(x)=-x^4$, for example. Then $F$ satisfies your additional assumption (it's nonpositive). But $F=-\infty$ on $L^2\setminus L^4$, which is a dense subset of $L^2$. So $F$ is not even continuous.

Comment: Is continuity of F a necessary condition for Gateaux/Frechet differentiability?

Comment: Of course. At least difference quotients needs to have limits, which needs continuity.

Answer (score 1):

The operator $F$ is Frechet from $L^\infty(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ without further assumptions.

In order to prove differentiability from $L^2$ to $\mathbb R$, one needs growth conditions: there exists $a,b\ge0$ such that
$$
|f(y)| \le a + b |y|^2
$$
and
$$
|f'(y)| \le a + b |y|
$$
for all $y\in \mathbb R$.
This makes $F(x)$ well defined for all $x\in L^2$.

To prove Gateaux differentiability: show directional differentiability first. Convergence of difference quotients can be argued with Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and Taylor expansion of $f$. The directional derivative is given by
$$
F'(x; h) = \int_0^1 f'(x(s))h(s)ds,
$$
which is clearly linear and continuous with respect to $h\in L^2$. This proves Gateaux differentiability.

To show Frechet differentiability one can use Egorov's theorem.

I am pretty sure that these conditions are also necessary (See Appell and Zabrejko: Superposition operators - which is a great source of results of this type).