# Gateaux derivative of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider an integral operator $E\colon L^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$E(u) = \int_{\Omega} F(u(x))\,dx$

for $u\in L^{2}(\Omega)$. Suppose $F\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a derivative $f$. What other conditions do I need for $E$ to be Gateaux differentiable or have directional derivatives in a given direction $\psi \in L^{2}(\Omega)$? In particular, without any further assumptions, the [[wiki][1] article on Gateaux differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative#Example) gives the derivative as

$E^{\prime}(u)(\psi) = \lim\limits_{\tau\rightarrow 0} \int_{\Omega}\int^{1}_{0}f(u+ \tau s \psi)\psi \,ds\,dx = \int_{\Omega} f(u)\psi\,dx = \langle f(u),\psi \rangle$

Where the fundamental theorem of calculus was used to write the difference quotient as the inside integral. But it seems that to move the limit inside the integrals we need $f$ to be bounded or some growth condition to use dominated convergence theorem. Is this ${necessarily}$ true? Or can we get Gateaux differentiability without boundedness or any other conditions on $f$? In particular, I am worried that $f(u)\not\in L^{2}(\Omega)$.

I note a previous post talks [about a growth condition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801948/frechet-gateaux-differentiability-of-an-integral-operator-l2-r?rq=1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition would be that $f$ is continuous and of at most linear growth (i.e $|f(x)|\le K(1+|x|)$). The continuity can perhaps be weakened, but the growth condition seems close to necessary.